# Updating the permissions for the db user have any effect on existing connections?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, production-environment

I am thinking to add few more permissions to existing database user in a database in MySql db. This is in production and serving a large user group.
Will updating the permissions for the db user have any effect on existing connections?

Comment: IDK but one suggestion is you can simulate this by creating a local connection by running mySQL server locally. Try establish a connection, then update/revoke/add permissions to that user and check if the connection disrupts or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are established at login time.

MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.0 have added "Roles" for simplifying the establishment of permissions for large numbers of users.